# HybridAuth issue when removing session_start() from top of controller in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I can't use session_start() at top my controller as i am settings few sessions in my controller.. But if i don't add this at top of my controller the hybrid auth doesn't work at gets stuck at a page with error as below:

```
http://localhost/website/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1400740729
You cannot access this page directly.
```

Anyone came with such situations?

Comment: why do you need to start the session?? it is already started.and where do put the hybridauth library?

Comment: yup... when i remove the session_start() from top of my logincontroller it shows "You cannot access this page directly.". I have placed hybrid folder inside webroot... will that be a issue as it is working fine if i put session_start() at top of the controller...but i can't do that as i have so many session data already set...and will be lost if i call session_start() at top...

Comment: it might be because of session key. try to set a common session key.

Comment: the session is already started while accessing the login controller so i put session_start in the app controller currently it works fine....